# JPA select entities with date below parameter

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to select all entities where the value of the date field is below a given argument. However, my code doesn't seem to work.

**SomeEntity.java**

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {
  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
}
```

**SomeEntityRepository.java**

```
public interface SomeEntityRepositoryextends CrudRepository<SomeEntity, Long> {
    /**
     * Get all SomeEntity created before :until
     */
    @Query("Select e from SomeEntity e where e.date < :until")
    List<SomeEntity> findAllUntil(@Param("until") ZonedDateTime until);
}
```

My problem is this:

I will have a `SomeEntity` object where the date is `2019-08-31T10:00:00.000+02:00` and the value of `until` is `2019-08-24T10:00:00.000+02:00` (seven days earlier)

However, the object is still returned from the query.

I am using PostgreSQL 9.6

Comment: What type is your database column?

Comment: @Mick I'm using PostgreSQL, the column is a `bytea` which contains binary data.

Comment: you can only achieve in JPA what already works with SQL. How would you compare a binary date column in SQL?

Comment: I was under the assumption that JPA would figure out how to deal with the date column that it itself created. Guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every JDBC driver supports it. You can use one of following solutions:

1. Use TimeStamp instead of ZonedDateTime.
2. Use proper driver and follow its configuration requirements. For instance, for Oracle you may need to specify converter:

```
    @Convert(converter=OracleZonedDateTimeSeriliazer.class)
    private ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
```

For other databases you may need to implement such a convertor and specify it via `@Convert`.

Comment: @Cas Eliëns: If the answer is helpful, you can vote it up.